# streaming my screen with another client with java (code)

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, streaming, client-server

I've written a code to stream my screen with another person like skype or teamviewer so the program is working but just for 10 15 seconds and after that a white screen spotted with black points occurs here is the video of my application : [Video testing my application](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A4_6e_Nh3-A)

Server Code :

```
public void run() 
{
    boolean ok=true;
    try 
    {
        Socket s=Serveur.accept();
        ObjectInputStream lire_msg=new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        ObjectOutputStream envoyer_msg=new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        Rectangle rec=new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        Robot r= new Robot();
        BufferedImage img;
        while (ok) 
        {   
            img = r.createScreenCapture(rec);       
            //s.setSendBufferSize(65536);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            img.flush();
            if(ImageIO.write(img, "png",baos))
            {
                baos.flush();
                byte[] imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
                baos.close();
                envoyer_msg.write(imageInByte);
                envoyer_msg.flush();
                sleep(10);
            }                                       
    }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Client Code:

```
public void run() 
{
    try 
    {
        Image img=null;BufferedImage bimg;
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                bimg=ImageIO.read(lire_msg);
                img=SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bimg, null);
                }
            }catch(Exception e){}
            imgv.setImage(img);
            envoyer_msg.flush();
            sleep(10);
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Did you get any exception? Looks like a memory overflow.

Comment: If it works for a little while and then shows garbage, that seems like some kind of buffering issue to me. Is the `sleep(10)` call equivalent to `Thread.sleep(10)`? If so, you're sending the image up to 100 times per second, which may require too much bandwidth. Have you tried slowing down the frame rate to see if that helps?

Comment: have you solved this case?